# converting lists to dictionaries

Tags: python

I want to convert the data below into a dictionary with first column as Id number and rest of the elements as values

```
EDF768, Bill Meyer, 2456, Vet_Parking

TY5678, Jane Miller, 8987, AgHort_Parking

GEF123, Jill Black, 3456, Creche_Parking
```

So far I have opened the file and converted the data into a list. But I am not able to convert it into dictionary as its stating that equence is too long.

```
def createNameDict():
      file = open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\\ParkingData_Part2.txt","rt")
      contents = file.read()
      print contents,"\n"
      data_list = [line.split(",")  for line in contents.split("\n")]
      print data_list, "\n"
      dict_list = []
      data_dict = {}
      for line in data_list:
        key = line[0]
        value = (line[1], line[2], line[3])
        data_dict[key] = value
        data_dict = dict()

        dict_list.append(data_dict)
        # start dictionary over
        #print data_dict
      print (data_list)


      file.close()
```

The output I have is:

```
[['EDF768', ' Bill Meyer', ' 2456', ' Vet_Parking'], 
['TY5678', ' Jane Miller', ' 8987', ' AgHort_Parking'], 
['GEF123', ' Jill Black', ' 3456', ' Creche_Parking'], 
['ABC234', ' Fred Greenside', ' 2345', ' AgHort_Parking'], 
['GH7682', ' Clara Hill', ' 7689', ' AgHort_Parking'], 
['JU9807', ' Jacky Blair', ' 7867', ' Vet_Parking'], 
['KLOI98', ' Martha Miller', ' 4563', ' Vet_Parking'], 
['ADF645', ' Cloe Freckle', ' 6789', ' Vet_Parking'], 
['DF7800', ' Jacko Frizzle', ' 4532', ' Creche_Parking'], 
['WER546', ' Olga Grey', ' 9898', ' Creche_Parking'], 
['HUY768', ' Wilbur Matty', ' 8912', ' Creche_Parking']]
```

Can someone give me hints to convert the above list into dictionary like:

```
{'EDF768': ' Bill Meyer', ' 2456', ' Vet_Parking'}
```

Comment: That last example is not a valid dictionary structure.

Comment: You need to clarify whether you want a single dictionary with multiple keys, or a list of single key dictionaries (I think that you're going for the latter, but recommend that you go with the former. Are your keys (I'm assuming they are license plates) unique?

Comment: I agree with Joel, in that it seems this data structure would be better suited as just a dictionary and not a list of single key dicts. Please clarify what you want.

Answer (score 7):

Using the csv module:

```
import csv

d = {}

with open('ParkingData_Part2.txt','r') as fh:
    for line in csv.reader(fh):
        key = line.pop(0)
        d[key] = [item.strip() for item in line]

print d
```

returns

```
{'TY5678': ['Jane Miller', '8987', 'AgHort_Parking'], 'GEF123': ['Jill Black', '3456', 'Creche_Parking'], 'EDF768': ['Bill Meyer', '2456', 'Vet_Parking']}
```

Comment: I can't +1 enough. Use the correct tool for the job. That said, I would suggest using a list comprehension over map and `string.strip()` - mainly as `string.strip()` is deprecated in favour of the method on strings themselves. I've made that edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
  for line in data_list:
    key = line[0]
    value = (line[1], line[2], line[3])
    data_dict[key] = value
    dict_list.append(data_dict)
    data_dict = dict()
```

On the last line written above, you reset `data_dict()` to an empty dict *before* you append it to `dict_list`. Just switch the two lines around (as shown above).

**EDIT**
To get your output to be a pure dictionary (I'm assuming that all of your keys are unique):

```
def createNameDict():
    with open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\\ParkingData_Part2.txt","r") as f:
        contents = file.read()
    print contents,"\n"
    data_list = [line.split(",")  for line in contents.split("\n")]
    print data_list, "\n"
    data_dict = {}
    for line in data_list:
        data_dict[line[0]] = line[1:]
    print (data_dict)
    return data_dict
```

Note that your desired out put is a little ambiguous--the `dict` example you gave is not properly formatted and will generate a SyntaxError. I believe you mean `{'EDF768': ('Bill Meyer', ' 2456', ' Vet_Parking')}`

Comment: I think for clarity you should probably just list it in the right format and then comment it that way.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little awkward the way you are building your dictionaries each time. Just simplify it:

```
  dict_list = []
  # data_dict = {}  get rid of this
  for line in data_list:
    data_dict = {line[0]: line[1:]}
    dict_list.append(data_dict)
```

No need to declare a dict and clear it each time.

If what you really want is just a dictionary, do this:

```
  data_dict = {} 
  for line in data_list:
    data_dict[line[0]] = line[1:]
```

Comment: @nrj: awesome. Dont forget to hit the green checkmark if this solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data_dict = {lsitem[0]:lsitem[1:] for lsitem in data_list}
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, use the csv module, it makes the reading of your file a lot easier:

```
import csv

def createNameDict():
    data_file = csv.reader(open('ParkingData_Part2.txt', 'rb'))
    return dict(
        (line[0], line[1:]) for line in data_file
    )
```

Comment: This is the clearest & most idiomatic from the solutions I've seen.